# How to join 2 data.tables using a time interval and a group-by

Tags: r, date, datetime, join, data.table

I have a data.table of frequently collected data:

```
set.seed(1)
t1 <- seq(from=as.POSIXct('2014-1-1'), to=as.POSIXct('2014-6-1'), by='day')
T1 <- data.table(time1=t1, group=rep(c('A', 'B'), length(t1)/2), value1=rnorm(length(t1)))
```

and a data.table of infrequently collected data:

```
t2 <- seq(from=as.POSIXct('2014-1-1'), to=as.POSIXct('2014-6-1'), by='week')
T2 <- data.table(time2=t2, group=rep(c('A', 'B'), length(t2)/2), value2='ArbitraryText')
```

For each row of `T2` I would like to find all of the rows in `T1` that fall between `T2$t2` and `T2$t2`minus 1 week, then take the average value of `T1$V2`, by `T2$group`.

So the number of rows in the resulting table would be exactly equal to the number of rows in `T2` and the "correct" value that should be returned for the second row of `T2` (the average value of those `T1$value` that are in `T1$group` B and fall between Jan 1 and Jan 22) would look like this:

```
          t2          group    value1            value2
2014-01-22 00:00:00     B     0.1674069     "Arbitrary Text"
```

I imagine the fist step would be setting the keys for each data.table:

```
setkey(T1, group, time1)
setkey(T2, group, time2)
```

I'm unsure of how to proceed. Curiously `T1[T2[time1 %between% c(t2, t2-604800)]]` yields only results between Jan 1 and Jan 8, despite the default `mult='all'`.

EDIT: I should point out that each of the intervals (`T2$time2` minus 3 weeks to `T2$time2`) overlap each other on purpose. This means that each row of `T1` "belongs" to more than one desired average because it falls into the interval specified by more than one row of `T2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a grouping vector within T1 that is constructed using T2 breakpoints passed to the cut.POSIXt function:

```
 T1[ , grp := cut(time1, breaks=T2[,time2]) ]
> str(T1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  151 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ time1: POSIXct, format: "2014-01-01 00:00:00" "2014-01-02 00:00:00" "2014-01-03 00:00:00" ...
 $ group: chr  "A" "B" "A" "B" ...
 $ value: num  -0.626 0.184 -0.836 1.595 0.33 ...
 $ grp  : Factor w/ 21 levels "2014-01-01 00:00:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
#------------------
> T1[, mean(value), by="grp"]
#----------------
                    grp          V1
 1: 2014-01-01 00:00:00  0.04475859
 2: 2014-01-08 00:00:00  0.01062880
 3: 2014-01-15 00:00:00  0.62024902
 4: 2014-01-22 00:00:00 -0.31364304
 5: 2014-01-29 00:00:00  0.02178433
 6: 2014-02-05 00:00:00  0.08238828
 7: 2014-02-12 00:00:00  0.12544920
 8: 2014-02-19 00:00:00  0.47033820
 9: 2014-02-26 00:00:00  0.29648943
10: 2014-03-05 00:00:00  0.20856893
11: 2014-03-12 01:00:00 -0.28046960
12: 2014-03-19 01:00:00 -0.22334306
13: 2014-03-26 01:00:00  0.25434429
14: 2014-04-02 01:00:00  0.48056376
15: 2014-04-09 01:00:00 -0.52624880
16: 2014-04-16 01:00:00  0.62330703
17: 2014-04-23 01:00:00  0.01092562
18: 2014-04-30 01:00:00  0.12544150
19: 2014-05-07 01:00:00 -0.15919531
20: 2014-05-14 01:00:00 -0.61236195
21: 2014-05-21 01:00:00 -0.37797879
22:                  NA -0.61483084
                    grp          V1
```

You don't get the same number of groups as events in T2 but rather that number minus 1. I didn't use setkey since my by call was to the constructed column. If it's only a one time use, then I'm not sure its needed.

Comment: What if some of the intervals in T2 overlap?

Comment: Right. What if they do? That would seem to be an entirely different question requiring a different set of data structures.

Comment: Then rows in T1 might belong to two different averages in T2. If I create a grouping vector in T1 each row can only belong to one average in T2.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify this in the question. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Well, I think it is quite a different question. Your edit does NOT provide an example for testing. You cannot have overlapping intervals with a single time column in T2. I suggest you start over with a new question.

Comment: Sure I can. What if I say "For each row of T2 I would like to find all of the rows in T1 that fall between T2$t2 and T2$t2 minus 3 weeks.." Then all of the intervals would overlap.